# clientaccesspolicy.xml in SharePoint online with Office 365

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-clientobject

Is it possible to place clientaccesspolicy.xml file into site root for the SharePoint Online, which is part of Office 365 subscription? The point is to use Silverlight CSOM from a Silverlight Application running in another environment (on-premise, or hosted). I couldn't find any solution for the clientaccesspolicy.xml. There are only work-arounds suggesting to combine the external (to the Office 365) Silverlight Application with a web/wcf/ria services, that would use the .net client object model to query the data.

Comment: It's amazing how haters can downvote 6 years old questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible in Office365 you share a webapplication with other users, so that would be a security issue.

To pull data you could use

- CLR CSOM
- SharePoint WebServices
- SharePoint RESTful interface (ListData.svc)